# Plugin Error: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I have a plugin error in my logcat

```
   10:08:28 PM Plugin Error
        Problems found loading plugins:
        Plugin "Google Analytics Uploader" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "SDK Updater" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "Google App Indexing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "Google Cloud Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
        Disable not loaded plugins
        Enable Android Support
        Open plugin manager
 10:08:32 PM Error Loading Project: Cannot load 3 facets Details...
```

This happened after I left my laptop to sleep and when I opened android studio, this error popped out. Now I cannot run my project.

Comment: This happened when my Surface unexpectedly 'blacked out'. Power issues are notorious with Surfaces, luckily this was the only thing corrupted this time.

Answer (score 120):

In short:

- **Windows** (and **Linux**): Go to File--> Settings--> Plugins --> Enable **Android Support**
- **Mac**:  Android Studio--> Preferences--> Plugins --> Enable **Android Support**

[image]

If you look at the error you'll find the solution too :

```
3- Disable not loaded plugins
2- Enable Android Support
1- Open plugin manager
```

Comment: Somehow Android Studio _lost_ Android Support - puzzling. This worked like a charm.

Comment: if you are experiencing trouble enabling the plugins try: disabling android support -> cancel -> enable again (this worked for me)

Comment: why does it keep dissabling?

Answer (score 64):

I ran into the same error. Here is how I fixed this, at least temporarily (until the pros show the best way to fix this).

```
(On a Mac) Go to Android Studio -> Preferences -> Plugins.
```

You'll notice that **"Android Support"** Plugin is unchecked. Uncheck the **"Google Cloud Testing"** plugin and then check the **"Android Support"** plugin. Hit the Apply button and then click **OK**. The IDE will ask you to **restart** to bring the changes into effect. Hit OK and when the IDE restarts, your code should be working fine.

Comment: Your solution is OK, you are pro bro ;)

Comment: this worked great! i thought i had to re-install Android Studio :p @EnXin should accept this answer for others who might also have this problem :)

Comment: I don't have the "Google Cloud Testing", so couldn't uncheck. But still your solution worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: You have just saved me from a world of pain, Thank brother!

Comment: @MiladFaridnia if you google the answerer's name, you'll see a lot of images of women. Please consider that people who are not "bro"s work in this industry.

Comment: @Chhanda Bhattacharyya   bro. you saved my day. +1 vote for you. Thanks again

Comment: Thanks a lot miss.

Answer (score 28):

Go to `Settings->Plugins->IDE Settings` and just disable and enable again needed plugins.
Apply changes when you enable/disable.

Comment: No option of IDE in Settings >plugins

Comment: or file-->settings-->plugins

Comment: Installation got corrupted, on installation again and again, it shows only this message
Missing essential plugin:

  org.jetbrains.android

Please reinstall Android Studio from scratch.

Answer (score 16):

go as flow file-->settings-->plugins.
then uncheck the red options.
apply settings You will get error message no problem.
recheck the unchecked options.
press ok.
it will request to restart android studio press ok button and it will solve the problem and work again.

Comment: Worked for me, but GOOGLE, why should we do those things :( it is not user-friendly

Comment: This solved my problem.  I had to uncheck half a dozen plugins, close the AS, start it again, check those unchecked plugins, close AS, restart AS.  Not sure if it is related, but I had to delete workspace.xml because AS could not load it.

Answer (score 14):

- Open the file c:\users\username.AndroidStudio2.3\config\disabled_plugins.txt
- delete the line "org.jetbrains.android"
- restart Android Studio

Comment: Or `~/.AndroidStudio<version>/config/disabled_plugins.txt`.

Answer (score 10):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055520/1587329's solution also works in Linux:

> File--> Settings--> Plugins --> Enable Android Support

[image: screenshot settings plugins]

Or just click **Reset** in the top right.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same issue and was unable to enable Android Support plugin. Then I disable Google Cloud plugins and Firebase plugins and then enable the Android Support plugin. After AS restart I was able to re enable Google Cloud and Firebase plugins.

Comment: This saved me hours. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I too faced this issue, If you uncheck then check on any dependency(red colour) plugin then IDE will prompt a dialog to enable "Android Support" accept it and restart IDE problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

if you are installing on a PC that has set default language other then english(in my case, it was hindi), then android studio wont start. so first change your system language to english. i have faced this problem two times.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with me was that I imported android studio settings from another PC which had different user_name. the SDK location were hence set to c:/users/mmstq/appdata/local/android/android-sdk 
But luckily I had my previous settings backed up.
Which had SDK locations as c:/users/matlo/appdata/local/android/android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I faced the issue after updating the Android studio to '3.6.1', I just navigated to plugin and updated Flutter plugins, then restarted the IDE. This worked for me