# Plugin 'org.jetbrains.android' failed to initialize and will be disabled. Please restart Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I left my computer to sleep with Android Studio open and this suddenly happens to me now.

I get this error when Android Studio starts and it forces me to restart it. Also, when it does restart, I have a bunch of errors of other plugins telling me that the plugin “Android Support” is disabled. I tried the solution of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908267/plugin-error-required-plugin-android-support-is-disabled/37915320#37915320) with no avail.

Now, in the menu, under tools, I don't even have the AVD Manager nor the SDK Manager anymore!!!

I am at my workplace getting crazy with this. Please help!!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it was not a sleep problem, it happens to me all the time whenever i try to change my system's language to other than ENGLISH. 
for example when i try to install android studio on a PC that has its default system language HINDI, then this problem comes. because by changing this, date time formats becomes unreadable to android studio.
Simple solution is- dont change your system language and keep it as English.