# Error running 'app': Unknown run configuration type AndroidRunConfigurationType

Tags: android

When I run android studio I am getting this error :

```
Error running 'app': Unknown run configuration type AndroidRunConfigurationType
```

can any one help me this error.

Answer (score 7):

I had faced this issue importing flutter project after upgrading android studio.

Note: Android studio will not install Flutter plugin after studio update.

Run: flutter doctor ( to find flutter related issues though)

Installing flutter plugin:

File->Settings->Plugins->Enter "flutter" in the search bar->Install->Restart IDE

Answer (score 3):

Check this answer: [Plugin Error: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908267/plugin-error-required-plugin-android-support-is-disabled#40055520)

Verify that you do not have some of the plugins disabled.