# Android studio is not showing any android related options

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I don't know what happened but suddenly i started getting these error messages.

```
Plugin Error
                    Problems found loading plugins:
                    Plugin "Android Games" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Android NDK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Android APK Support" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Developers Samples" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Cloud Tools For Android Studio" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Test Recorder" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Firebase Testing" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Google Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Firebase Services" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "App Links Assistant" was not loaded: required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.
                    Plugin "Fire... (show balloon)
```

and I am just unable to create any new android app, or run the current app.

This is what i am getting when trying to create a new project.

[image]

There are also no android `avd` `sdk manager` options available.

I have just updated Android Studio and now using `3.1.3`
[image]

Comment: Maybe this answer would help it has nearly similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/40055520/8126119

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The log has already tell you what the problem is,

> required plugin "Android Support" is disabled.

Then you just need to enable it. In the `Plugin` page of `Settings`, tick the plugin `Android Support`, then `OK` and `Restart` Android Studio.

Comment: Thanks Geno :) I wasted 5 hours on it. Thanks again !!:)

Comment: I had this message, when the plugin was enabled. After I ticked off and tick it on again, the plugin was acknowledged.

Comment: @cyanide I think it is better to ask another question, with detailed log and phenomenon.